# How do you retrieve HTTP2 frame settings in a Spring Cloud Zuul filter with Jetty embed server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, embedded-jetty, netflix-zuul

**Background**

I'm currently working on a project that looks at various HTTP passive fingerprinting techniques for the purpose of security. Some aspects of the request I plan to fingerprint include the client hello, header order, HTTP2 frame settings, and HTTP2 pseudo header order. So far I have implemented a solution to retrieve the cipher suites, compression methods, and extensions from the client hello by extending Jetty's `org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.Server` class to wrap SSLEngine instances. I can then access the client hello data in a Zuul filter as shown below:

```java
private static final String SSL_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE = "org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.request.ssl_session";

@Override
public Object run() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();

    SSLSession sslSession = (SSLSession) request.getAttribute(SSL_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE);
    ClientHello clientHello = (ClientHello) sslSession.getValue("client-hello");
        
    return null;
}
```

More information about HTTP2 fingerprinting:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/white-paper/passive-fingerprinting-of-http2-clients-white-paper.pdf

**Issue**

Although Spring, Netflix Zuul, and Jetty embedded server have thorough documentation I have been unable to find a way to achieve a similar sort of solution for retrieving HTTP2 frame setting.

Comment: Are you asking about Jetty Client, or Jetty Server? (it's unclear from the examples)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Hey man thank you for the response, the question refers to Jetty embedded server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal code example to elaborate on [@sbordet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1215076/sbordet)'s answer.

> You can extend HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory and override protected > ServerSessionListener newSessionListener(Connector connector, EndPoint > endPoint) to return your custom implementation (that may delegate to the original implementation).

**MyServerSessionListener.java**

```
public class MyServerSessionListener implements ServerSessionListener {

    private final ServerSessionListener delegate;

    public MyServerSessionListener(ServerSessionListener delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onSettings(Session session, SettingsFrame settingsFrame) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> settings = settingsFrame.getSettings();

        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        context.set("http2-frame-settings", settings);

        delegate.onSettings(session, settingsFrame);
    }

}
```

**MyHTTP2ConnectionFactory.java**

```
public class MyHTTP2ServerConnectionFactory extends HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory {

    public MyHTTP2ServerConnectionFactory(HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration) {
        super(httpConfiguration);
    }

    public MyHTTP2ServerConnectionFactory(HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration, String... protocols) {
        super(httpConfiguration, protocols);
    }

    @Override
    protected ServerSessionListener newSessionListener(Connector connector, EndPoint endPoint) {
        ServerSessionListener delegate = super.newSessionListener(connector, endPoint);
        return new MyServerSessionListener(delegate);
    }

}
```

**MyFilter.java**

```
public class MyFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    ...

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

        Map<Integer, Integer> http2FrameSettings = (Map<Integer, Integer>) context.get("http2-frame-settings");

        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extend `HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory` and override `protected ServerSessionListener newSessionListener(Connector connector, EndPoint endPoint)` to return your custom implementation (that may delegate to the original implementation).

In this way, you have access to the low-level HTTP/2 frames (as objects, not in byte format) which may allow you to fingerprint the client.